# How to Using React Routing Navigate instead Redirect in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I saw this in a tutorial

In the Navigation Component

```
<li><NavLink to='/'>Home</NavLink></li>
```

In another Component

```
import Navigation from './Headers/Navigation' 
import Home from './Body/Home'
<Navigation />   
<Switch>
<Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
<Redirect from ='/' to='/Home'/>
<Switch />
```

I tried to learned the latest update and tried the above code by :

```
<Routes>
<Route path='/' element={<Navigate to='/Home' />} />
<Routes>
```

But what I really want doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

You *still need* to render the route you are redirecting to. Note that for the redirect to work correctly in the `Switch` component the `Home` component needs to render on a path ***other than*** `"/"` otherwise `Home` will match and render and the `Redirect` will never be reached.

v5

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
  <Redirect from ='/' to='/home'/>
<Switch />
```

v6

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
  <Route path='/' element={<Navigate to='/home' replace />} />
<Routes>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
...
<Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/Home' />} />
...
```

Comment: It's not working

Comment: You are talking about the default route, right?
I mean the default route when the requested route is not present in your routes.